# How can I add background shading to a web site background?

Tags: css

I have a web site with a very simple background:

```
 background-color: #e9e8ed;
```

What are the ways I can add some shading to this so it's a bit darker at the top than the bottom. I have seen a site that uses a .png.  Is this better than applying some CSS. Note my site is for browsers IE9 and above.

Comment: I think you can use some sort of css gradient http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: you can use gradient style  to do this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css gradients to do this...

For ex-

```
   #grad {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0     */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax */
   }
```

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) link may help you..

And by using [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) link use you can generate code for your gradient..